# Disabling the flickering of overlapping planes

Tags: scenekit

You know, when there are for example two planes in the same position, in different colors, they will start kind of battling against each other so some parts are another texture and some parts other.

I think that Scenekit's renderingOrder should fix this, but i couldn't get it to work. I gave planeA 0 for renderingOrder and planeB 1, but nothing happened.

So basically i want to have two planes in the same position, but i want another to be "dominative" so that the dominative plane will be rendered, and not the other.

Comment: (2022) Note that nowadays Apple expose the **depth buffer** in a simple way, so it's easy to fix

Answer (score 8):

This is commonly referred to as Z-fighting, and has been an issue in 3D for as long as 3D has existed.

*There are two basic, and not ideal, ways to deal with this, for what I currently understand of your situation:*

**1.** Remove the plane you don't want to be seeing, until you need it, probably when the camera goes around the other side, or some other condition changes, at which point you'll need to add the plane you need, and remove the other.

**2.** Ever so slightly separate them in "Z space", or whatever space makes sense to push them just so slightly apart. This can be an incredibly small amount, so small that it's impossible for the viewer to perceive that the planes are not in exactly the same space.

Comment: (2022) Note that nowadays Apple fortunately expose the depth buffer in a simple way, so it's easy to fix in a non-hacky way

Answer (score 1):

#### For 2022. Fortunately the solution is now simple, tweak the use of the depth buffer.

```
for i in 0..<theRelevantNodes.count {
    let n = theRelevantNodes[i]
    n.geometry?.firstMaterial?.readsFromDepthBuffer = false
}
```

Typically you just want to disable using the depth buffer information, and fortunately this is now easy.

`.writesToDepthBuffer` is also available.

And indeed - if actually necessary - you can explicitly set the `.renderingOrder` of each item. Note that `.renderingOrder` is a property of the node itself, not the material.

A full discussion of depth buffers is beyond the scope of a QA, but fortunately there are only four possibilities with the two booleans, so try all four!

Be aware that if you are using focus effects, it may be affected.

If relevant, draw performance may be affected one way or the other.

Comment: Epic. Good to see you back. And away from Unity ;)

Answer (score 0):

Having a similar problem with overlapping boxes representing vertical planes.

Here's a solution that might work for you if you're not using transparent nodes (I do, so my issue remains, I'll update when it's resolved):

Use a flattened node that contains all your planes geometries. You can flatten all node's childrenusing `flattenedClone()`. Then flatten every time you're adding more plane nodes, i.e:

```
class myClass {
    //Accumulate planes into this node
    var flattenedNode = SCNNode()

    func addPlaneNode(_ newPlane: SCNNode) {
        flattenedNode.removeFromParentNode()
        flattenedNode.addChildNode(newPlane)
        flattenedNode = flattenedNode.flattenedClone()
        rootNode.addChildNode(flattenedNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: the shaders definietly seem to have trouble w/ transparent planes, you're right. did you ever stumble on a solution to this, @AvishayCohen ?   if you have two slightly overlapping (transaparent) planes, they fight - doesn't make any sense

Comment: Ah, Apple expose the depth buffer easily, so no problem ...